# How would I go about appending to a table row from within a jquery each function

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

In the following code $j is the jquery object.  I was wondering why I can append to the tbody tag fine, however I cant to the tr tag via either of the selectiors: tr tbody or tr.  How can I append to the table row correctly?  Thank you for your help.

```
var $this = $j('<table><thead></thead><tbody><tr></tr></tbody></table>');
$j.each(settings.columns, function(i, val) {
        $j('<td></td>').appendTo($this.children('tbody tr')); 
        // Doesnt work with tr selector either, but works with tbody
        // More code
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`children`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/children) only finds immediate children (thus why `<tbody>` works), you want [`find`](http://docs.jquery.com/Traversing/find) otherwise:

```
$j('<td></td>').appendTo($this.find('tbody tr'));
```

You could also use `$this` as the [context](http://docs.jquery.com/Core/jQuery#expressioncontext) of the query:

```
$j('<td></td>').appendTo($j('tbody tr', $this));
```